# Converting Scientific Notation in Column to Decimal and Converting Decimal to Integers without rounding

Tags: python, pandas, integer, decimal

Hello I have a DataFrame that looks like this. And I want to convert the whole column from a Scientific notation to a Decimal.

And After I convert them to Decimals, I want to convert them into and integer without making them whole numbers.

Please help.

df1 = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/노후교량/DZ_Middle_G/20km_hr_lane1_acc_middle_girder.csv')

df1.head()

```
output:

            DZ_middle_G_L1_20km
0           1.021e-003
1           1.597e-003
2           1.564e-003
3           1.031e-003
4           3.022e-004
```

So I want my final output to be:

```
            DZ_middle_G_L1_20km
0           0.001021
1           0.001597
2           0.001564
3           0.001031
4           0.0003022
```

Thank you very much

Comment: try adding, ``pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.5f' % x)``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This changes to integer:

```
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.7f' % x)
df[list(df.columns)] = df[list(df.columns)].astype('float64').apply(np.int64)
print(df)
```

Comment: @KimYejun Try the new code I just updated :(

Comment: I don't know why, but nothing is working :(

Comment: @KimYejun i made a small change. try again 

Comment: Wow. That worked. Thank you very much! Can you help me converting it to int? I can't add or multiply any values because they are float :(

Comment: @KimYejun okay, now i changed it to integer. try again. also, please mark me as best answer 